Unexpected behavior of SetDelayed and Derivative
Let
A = x^2 

and define a function
f[x_] := A

Computing D[f[x],x] gives 2x, as expected.  But f'[x] gives zero.  Why is this?  Does this mean that D[f[x], x] and f'[x] are not really equivalent?
This problem does not arise when using Set: f[x] = A. Then both D and ' give the same result.

The documentation, referred to by @Roman, used to be accurate IIRC; however, things change.
This yields the desired answer, which is correct in one way of looking and absolutely incorrect in another. I cannot stress enough it is the wrong way to use the system.
Clear[f];
A = System`Private`DerivativeX[1]^2;
f[x_] := A;
{f'[x], f'[y]}
(*  {2 x, 2 y}  *)

The system now takes the following steps to find Derivative[...][f]: Evaluate f[System`Private`DerivativeX[1], System`Private`DerivativeX[2],...] with a System`Private`DerivativeX[k] for each argument and k equal to 1, 2,... up to the number of arguments; then differentiate with respect to these arguments; then construct a pure function with Slot[k] (#k) replacing the corresponding argument.

I disagree with @Roman's conclusion that Set is to be preferred over SetDelayed. In fact, it's the opposite. Use Set when you're doing something bad and don't want to (or are unable to) refactor your code to do things write. You might be unable to if you rely on user input, and you want your program to meet the user where they are and not drag them kicking and screaming deep into the programming environment.
I would recommend a choice of two ways: Use formulas not function, or program your functions properly. Don't mix the approaches. If you have to, then you'll have to use Set[], Evaluate[] as well as Block[] if you need to be safe.
First way: Use Set for formulas.
ClearAll[f];
a = x^2; (* avoid starting with capitals, esp. single letters *)
f = a;
D[f, x]
(*  2x  *)

Second way: Use SetDelayed for functions.
ClearAll[a, f];
a[x_] := x^2; (* make dependence of a[] explicit *)
f[x_] := a[x];
f'[x]
(*  2 x  *)


Let's go back to the OP's definition. Formally, it is a constant function: no matter what the input, the output is a. The derivative of a constant is zero.
ClearAll[a, f];
a = x^2;
f[x_] := a;

f[x]
f[y]
f[x + h] - f[x]
(*
x^2
x^2
0
*)

One sees this in the definition or downvalues of f:
DownValues[f]
(*  {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> a}  *)

This replacement rule is applied when f is evaluated. The pattern x_ matches the argument in an expression f[argument] and the expression x matches will replace the literal occurrences of the symbol x in the right-hand side of the rule, of which there are none. No replacement means a constant function. This is sometimes described in terms of local versus global variables (or symbols), but I don't feel this is quite as accurate as the notion of "literal replacement." (For one thing, the symbol x is Global`x in everything above.)
Note we have a and not x^2 in the downvalue for f. That is because SetDelayed does not evaluate the right-hand side of the := when it constructs the downvalue. That is documented and is a feature. @Roman hints at the following possibility, a hybrid formula-function workaround:
ClearAll[a, f, x];
a = x^2;
f[x_] = a;
f'[y]
(*  2 y  *)

There is also this possibility:
ClearAll[a, f, x];
a = x^2;
f[x_] := Evaluate[a];
f'[y]
(*  2 y  *)

Now these two possibilities fail if we give x a value:
ClearAll[a, f, x];
a = x^2;
x = 3;
f[x_] := Evaluate[a];
f'[y]
(*  0  *)

This is a case where you could use Block:
ClearAll[a, f, x];
a = x^2;
x = 3;
Block[{x},
  f[x_] := Evaluate[a]
  ];
f'[y]
(*  2 y  *)


The x in the definition of A is not the same as the "local variable" x that you use to define the function f. This does not matter for Set, but bites for SetDelayed.
More specifically, the documentation for Derivative says:

f' is equivalent to Derivative[1][f], and
Derivative[n][f] is internally evaluated as D[f[#],{#,n}]&, which uses a special internal variable # instead of forcing the variable to be x, as you intended.

In other words, the evaluation of f'[x] actually first computes f' and then applies it to x, so something like (f')[x]. But to go from f to f' makes no reference to the global variable x, only to the function itself, and so f' returns the pure function 0&, because f does not depend on its argument directly:
f'
(*    0 &    *)

Tl;dr:

Do not use SetDelayed unless you really have to. Set is much more natural for defining functions. I know some people will disagree with this; and you can make up your own mind by learning about all the differences between Set and SetDelayed.
Do not mix global and local variables, and especially try to avoid shadowing a global by a local.

